# Python-docx-template skip tag if variable does not exist

Tags: python

I'm learning [docxtpl](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and I can't find a way to not show a line in an if or if/else if the variable doesn't exist. Consider the following where address2 is optional:

```
{{ name }}
{{ address1 }}
{{ address2 }}
{{ city }} {{ state }} {{ zip }}
```

with the following context:

```
{
    'name': "Joe Bob",
    'address1': "123 Apple Way",
    'city': 'Pleasant',
    'state': 'CA',
    'zip': '94566'
}
```

I would hope it would render something like:

```
Joe Bob
123 Apple Way
Pleasant CA 94566
```

But instead it renders:

```
Joe Bob
123 Apple Way

Pleasant CA 94566
```

I've tried to do some merging with an if/else and using the {%- like so but it hasn't worked. I read any merging with a {%- needs to have the tag on its own line.

```
{{ name }}
{{ address1 }}
{% if address2 %}{{ address2 }}
{% else %}
{{ no_defined_variable }}{% endif %}
{{ city }} {{ state }} {{ zip }}
```

The only alternative I can think of is putting it into a loop but I think there will be some more situations where I can't do that that I'll come across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

```
{{ name }}
{{ address1 }}
{%p if address2 %}
{{ address2 }}
{%p endif %}
{{ city }} {{ state }} {{ zip }}
```

The main thing to note is that the {%p has to be on a new line entirely.

I've yet to figure it out for more than just text. For example, a document with section A and B, and either A or B could show, or A and B together. An if statement around the whole section does keep it from rendering, but my template has them all on a new page, so I get a blank page in the middle of my document.